# ¿Cómo averiguar el tipo de sentencia MySql en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

En una aplicación PHP necesito saber si una **sentencia SQL** es de tipo *INSERT*, *UPDATE*, *DELETE*, ... ¿Hay una forma de averiguarlo, que no sea una busqueda de strings dentro de la sentencia de una de estas palabras clave?, quiero decir ¿alguna función nativa de PHP?

Comment: Supongo que quieres que sea con MySQLi porque tiene esa etiqueta; pero, ¿importa si es antes o después de ejecutar la sentencia? ¿Se pueden ejecutar sentencias adicionales?

Comment: Y por curiosidad, ¿con qué finalidad quieres saber esto?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es identificar si viene la palabra dentro del string de consulta

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ....';

if (strpos($sql, 'SELECT') !== false) {
    //ES SELECT
}
```

Lo mismo para las otras consultas...

Sin embargo, te recomiendo que crees una funcion que reciba dos parametros uno la consulta sql y otro el tipo de consulta :

```
function consultaSQL($consulta, $tipo) {
     switch ($tipo) {
     case 0:
        //SELECT
        break;
     case 1:
        //INSERT
        break;
     case 2:
        //DELETE
        break;
    }
}
```

Y la llamas asi :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ....';
this.consultaSQL($sql, 0)
```

Comment: Sí, tengo una función implementada que hace exactamente eso. Las busquedas las hago además en función de la posibilidad de encontrar la ocurrencia, que puede variar para cada sistema... Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna función propia de PHP que haga lo mismo.

Comment: a perfecto, por lo que sé no hay ninguna

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas clases auxiliares para gestionar la conexión a la base de datos y las consultas vas a tener distintas funciones según los tipos de consulta, con lo cuál podrías saberlo por la función utilizada.

Este es un ejemplo [https://github.com/bennettstone/simple-mysqli/blob/master/class.db.php](http://Classdb)

Por si está aproximación sirve a tu propósito.